# Backbone model fetch error

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, backbone.js

I try to load simple JSON object from static json file, but fetch is triggering error handler.

```
        this.model.fetch({ 
            error: function(){ 
                console.log(arguments); 
            }
        });
```

Then arguments[1].state is 200 and request looks good.

This model is

```
Backbone.Model.extend({ 
defaults: {
  title: "no title loaded",
  body : "no body loaded",
  parm1 : "no parm 1",
  parm2 : "no parm 2"
},
url : 'api/data.json'
});
```

data.json

```
{
title: "My New Demo", 
    body: "This is my first demo text!"
}
```

Where can i find error details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON keys must be quoted.

```
{
    "title": "My New Demo", 
    "body": "This is my first demo text!"
}
```

Comment: LOL, sometimes it is realy hard :O) ... Tnx!
I wonder that it does not trigger parse error or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your server is using 'application/json' as the mimeType. Backbone uses $.ajax under the covers and it might not understand the .json file.